# How is the relationship between template styles and menus stored in Joomla 3.x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, development, templates, menu-item

I'm working on a tool that imports content for a new language. As part of that process, I'm creating a copy of a template style specific to the new language. After making a copy of the template style and setting certain values in the new template style, I also need to change which menu items are associated with the template. In the admin interface, it's easy to see and set these associations, but I can't seem to find where they are stored.

Does anyone know which table(s) the associations are stored in, or if there is a Joomla function to call to set/unset associations between a template style and menu items?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`template_style_id` column in `#__menu` table.